# Reactor lazy pagination with expand

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Based on [How to collect paginated API responses using spring boot WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274568/how-to-collect-paginated-api-responses-using-spring-boot-webclient)

I created the following crawler class

```
class GitlabCrawler(private val client: WebClient, private val token: String) {

    fun fetchCommits(project: URI): Flux<Commit> {
        return fetchCommitsInternal(project).expand { cr: ClientResponse? ->
                val nextUrl = getNextUrl(cr)

                nextUrl?.let { fetchCommitsInternal(URI.create(it)) }
                        ?: Mono.empty<ClientResponse>()
        }.limitRate(1)
                .flatMap { cr: ClientResponse? -> cr?.bodyToFlux(Commit::class.java) ?: Flux.empty() }


    }

    private fun getNextUrl(cr: ClientResponse?):String? {
        // TODO replace with proper link parsing
        return cr?.headers()?.header(HttpHeaders.LINK)?.firstOrNull()
                ?.splitToSequence(",")
                ?.find { it.endsWith("rel=\"next\"") }
                ?.let { it.substring(it.indexOf('<') + 1, it.lastIndexOf('>')) }
    }

    private fun fetchCommitsInternal(url: URI): Mono<ClientResponse> {
        return client.get()
                .uri(url)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .header("Private-Token", token)
                .exchange()
    }
}


data class Commit(
        val id: String,
        val message: String,
        @JsonProperty("parent_ids") val parentIds: List<String>,
        @JsonProperty("created_at") val createdAt: String)
```

I'd like to avoid unnecessary request, but it performs more request than needed to fulfill the request.

```
gitlabCrawler.fetchCommits(URI.create("https://...")).take(15).collectList().block()
```

Would only need one request as each page contains 20 entries, but it starts the second page request. It seems to always request one more page than necessary. I tried using `limitRate` but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Is there a way to make it lazy, i.e., only request the next page when the current is exhausted?

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that it actually performs the request? `fetchCommitInternal` being invoked means that `WebFlux` "prepared" the request, not necessarily that it was executed (ie. subscribed).

The following simplification of your use case shows the difference:

```
private static Tuple2<Integer, Flux<Integer>> nextPage(int index, int pageSize) {
    System.out.println("prepared a request for page " + index);
    return Tuples.of(index, Flux.range((pageSize * (index - 1)) + 1, pageSize));
}

@Test
public void expandLimitedRequest() {
    int pageSize = 5;
    Flux.just(nextPage(1, pageSize))
        .doOnSubscribe(sub -> System.out.println("requested first page"))
        .expand(page -> {
            int currentPage = page.getT1();
            if (currentPage < 3) {
                int nextPage = currentPage + 1;
                return Flux.just(nextPage(nextPage, pageSize))
                           .doOnSubscribe(sub -> System.out.println("requested page " + nextPage));
            }
            return Flux.empty();
        })
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .flatMap(Tuple2::getT2)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .take(8)
        .blockLast();
}
```

Prints:

```
prepared a request for page 1
requested first page
[1,FluxRange]
1
2
3
4
5
prepared a request for page 2
requested page 2
[2,FluxRange]
6
7
8
prepared a request for page 3
```

As you can see, it prepares the request for page 3 but never execute it (because the `take` downstream cancels the `expand` before that).

Comment: From the logs it looks like the request is done eagerly with `.exchange()`, I have two `Received response` log entries with the headers. This also happens if I only `take(1)`.